Different identity cookie name for specific user agent
I would like to set a custom ASP.NET Core Identity cookie name for users that login via mobile app.
I get this info from user-agent string.
I would like to know how to configure different names of the default .Aspnetcore.Identity.Application cookie name.
I am using .NET8 and Umbraco 13
I tried to create a custom CookieAuthenticationEvents:
 public class CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
 {
     public override Task SigningIn(CookieSigningInContext context)
     {
         var userAgent = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

         // Define logic for naming cookies based on the user-agent
         if (userAgent.Contains("custom-user-agent"))
         {
             context.Options.Cookie.Name = "MobileAuthCookie";
         }
         else
         {
             context.Options.Cookie.Name = "DefaultAuthCookie";
         }

         return base.SigningIn(context);
     }
 }

and register it:
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(cookie => cookie.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents));

But the SigningIn method is never executed when I log in.

Why do you want this, what exactly are you trying to achieve by this?

I have an old mobile app, which I cannot change, but I'd like it to work with the updated backend system, which previously used .ASPXAUTH cookie instead of .AspNetCore.Identity.Application. And unfortulatelly the cookie name is hardcoded in mobile app.

To change the name of the cookie, then it is controlled by the Authentication cookie handler, and you can control it using:
.AddCookie("cookie", options =>
{
   options.Cookie.Name = ".ASPXAUTH";
});


Its been a while since the question was asked, but I found a solution.
In your startup class, you can override the default options like so:
builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>
    (IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events.OnSigningIn = async (context) =>
    {

        var userAgent = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

        // Define logic for naming cookies based on the user-agent
        if (userAgent.Contains("custom-user-agent"))
        {
            context.Options.Cookie.Name = "MobileAuthCookie";
        }
        else
        {
            context.Options.Cookie.Name = "DefaultAuthCookie";
        }
    };
});

This way it worked perfectly for me, it overrides the default IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme name

As you can see in this video, I requested a login without a custom header and got send the DefaultAuthCookie.
In this video, I requested a login with a custom header and got send the MobileAuthCookie.
Now when I call a protected endpoint unauthenticated, I am given a 404 response.

However, when I call the endpoint with either the DefaultAuthCookie or the MobileAuthCookie. I am given the appropriate response.


Hope this helps!

Unfortunatelly this does not work properly. If you just try one by one it works. When you login with user with one user agent and get the cookie and meanwhile you login with from another useragent, the first one's cookie becomes useless and the the first user needs to re-login. This change happens on each Sign in, but it changes the cooke name globally for all. It should be somehow scoped to each request and not signin.

The best option would be to configure a separate cookie with the correct name. Sign a user in using that cookie when their user agent is on the phone, instead of the default identity cookie.
